# Alternative to c# generic modifier "out" in Java

Tags: java, c#, generics

I'm trying to convert following c# code and behavior to Java but I'm struggling to find the right syntax or programming pattern.

In c# I can use ***out*** like in `interface IProxy<out Target>` which allows me to implicitly cast `IProxy<DerivedElement1>` to `IProxy<BaseElement>` but for Java I'm not aware of any similar generic modifiers.

```
class BaseElement {
    public static readonly Property<BaseElement> P1 = new Property<BaseElement>();
}
class DerivedElement1 : BaseElement {
    public static readonly Property<DerivedElement1> P2 = new Property<DerivedElement1>();
}
class DerivedElement2 : BaseElement {
    public static readonly Property<DerivedElement2> P2 = new Property<DerivedElement2>();
}

class Property<Owner> {
}

interface IProxy<out Target> {
}
class Proxy<Target> : IProxy<Target> {
}

class Program {
    static void doSomething<Target>(IProxy<Target> proxy, Property<Target> property) {
        // ...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Proxy<DerivedElement1> proxy1 = new Proxy<DerivedElement1>();

        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P1);
        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P2);

        // expected error
        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement2.P2);
    }
}
```

It is very important that the expected error appears at **compile time** and not at **run time**.

Are you aware of any applicable syntax or pattern that would allow me to implement the same behavior without any additional casting?

I hope you can point me in the right direction, thank you much for your help!

Comment: I guess this trail might help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html (This is not an answer because it's link-only - though I really think this is exactly what you are looking for.)

Comment: if you want to enforce that `Target` in the two arguments `(IProxy<Target> proxy, Property<Target> property` express the same type, no, you cannot do it without some workarounding.

Comment: thank you for the link, but if I use _wildcards_ then I don't get a compile time error if I use incompatible parameters (e.g. `doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement2.P2)`)

Comment: but, you could use a generic method like in`public static <Target> void doSomething(IProxy<Target> proxy, Property<Target> property) {` _and_ invoke it like `Program.<DerivedElement1>doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement2.P2)` and get your wanted compile time error.

Comment: that is correct, but it will not work for `doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P1);`

Comment: yep, in that case  you'll have to narrow down to `<BaseElement>doSomething()`

Comment: unfortunately `Program.<BaseElement>doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P1)` won't work because _proxy1_ cannot be casted to `Proxy<BaseElement>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use `Proxy<? extends Target>` to declare my proxy argument.

Here is the complete solution:

```
class BaseElement {
    public static final Property<BaseElement> P1 = new Property<BaseElement>();
}
class DerivedElement1 extends BaseElement {
    public static final Property<DerivedElement1> P2 = new Property<DerivedElement1>();
}
class DerivedElement2 extends BaseElement {
    public static final Property<DerivedElement2> P2 = new Property<DerivedElement2>();
}

class Property<Owner> {
}

class Proxy<Target> {
}

class App {
    static <Target>
    void doSomething(Proxy<? extends Target> proxy, Property<Target> property) {
        // ...
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        Proxy<DerivedElement1> proxy1 = new Proxy<DerivedElement1>();

        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P1);
        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement1.P2);

        // expected error
        doSomething(proxy1, DerivedElement2.P2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If Ive got you correctly you should have a look at [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) in Java.

### Sample Java Code

```
public class IProxy<T>{
      ....
}

public class Property<T>{
    ....
}
public class Program {
    public static void doSomething(<IProxy<T> iProxy, Property<T> property){
       ......
    }
}
```

Type Parameter Naming Conventions (not sure what Target is referring to in C#)

```
E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I am not sure how your code ensures that `doSomething(proxy, property)` can only be called with the right pair of arguments.

Comment: have a look at the link that I have sent. Generics in Java are good for compile time testing not run-time testing. As mentioned in the answer you can define the types by E,K,N etc.

Comment: For IProxy<Target> proxy, Property<Target> property you can pass IProxy interface with your target type etc

Comment: @user667967 answer is updated hope it helps. as mentioned it is a sample code.